# Public link for a picture in storage sub folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I save an image, I try to save in a subfolder like this:

```
/2020/3/myimagename.jpg
```

I can save file like this:

```
$yearMonthPath = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$currentYear.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$currentMonth;
$fileName = $userId."_".uniqid()."_".$fileName;
Storage::disk('local')->put($yearMonthPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fileName, file_get_contents($file));
```

Image files are now under:

```
/storage/app/2020/3/1_5e5fe9b93f37a_71a5d6e5c38bd2993c19a64229b383b1.jpg
```

I linked storage to public:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Due to the documentation, my expectation was to get public link for the image:

```
echo asset('storage/app/2020/3/'.$fileName);
```

This outputs the following link, which returns 404.

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/app/2020/3/1_5e5fe9b93f37a_71a5d6e5c38bd2993c19a64229b383b1.jpg
```

I also tried different combinations "public/2020...", "public/storage/2020...", but none of them worked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `public` disk. The `public` disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the `local` driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`.

```
Storage::disk('public')
```

Once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created, you can create a URL to the files using the asset helper:

```
echo asset('storage/2020/3/'.$fileName); // remove `app`
```